# Android App not allow licensed access to my own App (using the developer account)

Tags: android, google-play, android-lvl

Recently I published my first Android App on the Market Place (Trophy-to-Gamerscore Converter). It's a licensed app that worked perfectly during testing and once I publish it - that is to say I was able to access and use my own app on my Android Phone which syncs with my developer account.

I recently accidentally unpublished the app but quickly fixed this and got it straight back on the Market however no when I try and run my app I get a "Unlicensed" message. I tried re-installing and had a play around and found it is responding to the testing environment responses. I installed the exact .APK I uploaded and that is currently published so surely it should be running through Market License Management, see I am the developer and ultimately allowing me access right?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're the application developer -- and you have your developer account registered as the primary account on the phone -- then you cannot buy your own application.

Instead, Android Market will send whatever debug setting is listed here:

http://market.android.com/publish/editProfile

Note that the APK's package name has to match exactly so that the license server can find it.

Since we always return LICENSED for unpublished apps up until the point they're published, this behavior makes me believe you're not actually logged into the phone using the same account you have on your publisher account. In this case, you'll need to add the account on the phone tho the list of "test accounts" -- also on the page I linked to above.

Comment: I am logged into the phone with my developer account and I am receiving the test responses correctly however my app is now published but I am still receiving the test responses - I guess my question ultimately is if this is supposed to happen or am I supposed to receive a market managed response recognising I am the developer and returning LICENSED?